# Mount encrypted volumes from command line?

Tags: command-line, mount, encryption

If I have an encrypted external disk (or an internal disk that is not in fstab), I see an entry for it in Nautilus -- with an entry like "X GB Encrypted Volume".  I can click on this volume, and am prompted for a password to decrypt and mount the device.

But how do I do this from the command line?

[This wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage), and other docs I can find, only refer to GUI methods of decrypting the device; but this won't do in the context of headless servers or SSH logins.  Is there a simple way to get devices to mount to automatic locations in `/media` just like they would with the GUI?

(I'm not asking about encrypted home directories -- I'm aware of `ecryptfs-mount-private`.  This question is about additional encrypted volumes.)

Comment: +1 for drawing the distinction between the encryption of file systems as a whole and encrypted home directories

Comment: Continues. The distinction has become topical now that Ubuntu 18.04 has demoted the support for single directory encryption in favour of full disk encryption, according to https://askubuntu.com/q/1030572/446253 For some, including me, this is a source of difficulties in migrating to 18.04 seamlessly

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182387/how-to-mount-a-disk-encrypted-with-cryptsetupcrypto-luks-in-ubuntu-14-04 | https://superuser.com/questions/1134255/luks-on-ubuntu-16-04-unknown-filesystem-type-crypto-luks

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The steps in @Georg Schölly's answer did not work for me at the time, although they might work now, a few Ubuntu releases after. Back then, after the `sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume /media/my_device` step I got the error:

> mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

### Unlocking and mounting the disk with udiskctl

Instead, I used `udisksctl`, a command-line interface that interacts with the `udisksd` service.

Here's what worked (`/dev/sdb5` is the partition on my hard disk marked as `crypt-luks`):

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb5
udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

After typing the first command, you'll be prompted for your encryption passphrase. Once the encrypted partition is unlocked, the second command will mount it. If that's successful, you'll end up with a message *similar* to this:

```
Mounted /dev/dm-1 at /media/dpm/e8cf82c0-f0a3-41b3-ab28-1f9d23fcfa72
```

From there I could access the data :)

### Locking the disk with udiskctl

Unmount the device:

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

You'll need to deactivate all logical volumes in the `ubuntu-vg` volume group first. Otherwise you'll get an error along the lines of 'Device busy' if you try to lock it ([more info](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/11/16/how-to-mount-encrypted-lvm-logical-volume/)):

```
sudo lvchange -an ubuntu-vg
```

Then you'll be able to lock back the encrypted partition

```
udisksctl lock -b /dev/sdb5
```

### Notes

- The `udisksctl` commands are executed *without* `sudo`.
- **Device mapper names**: the `ubuntu--vg-root` naming might change across Ubuntu releases (e.g. I've seen it called `system-root` and `ubuntu-root` too). An easy way to find out the name is to run the following command *after unlocking the LUKS partition*:

  `ls -la /dev/mapper`

  Then looking at the output of the `ls` command, the name you'll need will be generally the one symlinked to `/dev/dm-1`
- **Device mapper names, alternative**: an alternative to the previous command is to run:

  `lsblk -e7`

  There you'll be able to see the device name mapping as a tree view. The `-e 7` option is used to exclude the loop devices (ID 7) created by installed snaps from the output. Simply to have less clutter.
- **Logical volume names**: you can run the `sudo lvs` command to find out the names of volume groups and logical volumes
- **Disks app**: the GNOME Disks app does not automatically deactivate the logical volumes before locking the partition. Even if you've successfully unlocked the partition via the GUI, you will need to go to the command line and execute the `sudo lvchange -an ubuntu-vg` command before you can lock it from the GUI.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because I suspect this is more or less what nautilus does using libudisks2. Also, I've tested this to work well as an unprivileged user.

Comment: I unfortunately get the error `Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d3 is not a mountable filesystem.` any advice?

Comment: @wawa I had the same problem and solved it in this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/895508/334823

Comment: It's not clear to me what I should type in place of /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root If I simply type it I get an error.  "Error looking up object for device /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root"

Comment: I needed `sudo` for both `udisksctl` commands, otherwise I get an error like `Error unlocking /dev/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorized: Not authorized to perform operation`.

Comment: Fast forward 5 years, I found myself having to rescue an encrypted partition again. I used an Ubuntu 18.04 live USB stick and followed the same steps I described back then. As before, they worked well and I did not need `sudo` to execute them.

Comment: @Selah, I extended the answer to better explain what device path to use for the mount. To mwfearnley: it might be worth looking at the permissions of the user you were logged in as.

Comment: This saved me a reinstall! Thank you! <3

Comment: This mounts the volume in read-only mode. Any way for this formulation to mount in read-write?

Answer (score 154):

Your volume is probably encrypted with LUKS, here's how to mount it:

You need:

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

To decrypt the volume:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 my_encrypted_volume
```

Now you can mount it as usual:

```
sudo mkdir /media/my_device
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume /media/my_device
```

To lock the container again, it needs to be unmounted first:

```
sudo umount /media/my_device
sudo cryptsetup luksClose my_encrypted_volume
```

To automatically put it in the `/media` location, use the udisks tool

```
sudo udisks --mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume
```

Comment: So I can't do it as a non-privileged user, either, even though I could via the GUI?

Comment: That actually depends on your system setting. I believe most commands should work as long as your system gives your user access to the devices.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 ships the `udisks2` package in place of `udisks`, and the former renames the tool `udisksctl`.

Comment: unfortunately did not work for me with ubuntu 16.04.  mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Comment: @Selah: Sounds like you're trying to decrypt something which is not a LUKS volume. Maybe you need to use something else than `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  I was trying to mount /dev/sda3 which is type crypt-luks according to GParted.

Comment: This worked for me!! https://askubuntu.com/questions/895478/opening-luks-encrypted-drive-in-nautilus-results-in-operation-cancelled/895508#895508

Comment: This worked for me like a charm. The best answer I've found on the Internet after searching up and down the Internet low and high. Thank you for the Awesome answer. What I don't understand is that I never had this problem with Ubuntu 16.04. It always auto mounted the drive, but this time something changed that it wouldn't ... Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: Needed [hints from this other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/485114/443400) in my case

Comment: This formulation fails on Ubuntu 22.04 with the error message: "unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'." At the first mount command.

Comment: Fix for LVM2_member error: When you do luksOpen, ls the contents of /dev/mapper. It'll probably have an xx--vg-root item in there. Mount that, not my_encrypted_volume.

Answer (score 33):

If you get this error:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

run:

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
sudo lvscan
```

then activate all LVM you see

```
sudo vgchange -ay
```

then re-run the mount:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume /media/my_device
```

Comment: The last line is not necessarily correct, as you may still end up with the same error. Rather, mount one of the drives listed with lvscan instead of `/dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume`

Comment: This did not work for me.  Same error mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.  Perhaps because I am booting from a flash drive?

Comment: @SeanScott thank you so much... I used the installer to encrypt my drive now I am trying to recover data and have to newly learn these things... d'oh

Comment: @Weasemunk thank you ! this was the problem !

Comment: In the context of a reinstall of NIXOS, this worked for me. Already had `lvscan` and `vgchange` available from the nixos-minimal iso.

Answer (score 16):

One problem i ran into, was **duplicate volume groups**: Both my recovery system and the drive to be recovered were ubuntu systems with LVM. This is, why I had two `ubuntu-vg` volume groups (`vgdisplay` would display both, each with their own UUID, but i couldn't get to their logical volumes).

My solution builds on the answer of Georg:

- Boot off a live-linux (so that you don't run into the duplicate volume group name)
- `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdaX my_encrypted_volume`
- enter your passphrase when prompted
- `sudo vgscan` should now pick up the contained volumes/groups.
- DRAGONS AHEAD: WE'RE NOW CHANGING THE VOLUME GROUP NAME. **YOU WILL NOT BE ABLE TO BOOT THAT DRIVE AFTERWARDS!**

  use `sudo vgrename ubuntu-vg ubuntu-vg2` to rename the volume group.

  If you need to boot off that drive, you can do these steps again, but rename your volume group *back* to ubuntu-vg. A different possibility is to alter your boot configuration to the new vg-name.

Now that the duplicate vg-name is resolved, i can boot back into my regular system, redo the `cryptsetup...`, `vgscan` and then mount `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg2-root` anywhere you like.

Comment: Looks like you can also do `sudo vgdispay` to find the UUID and use that instead of the duplicate name in order to do the rename of just the one volume. That is, grabbing the UUID and then doing `sudo vgrename <uuid> old` worked for me.

Comment: I can't test Mike's suggestion right now, but If it works, it's better than renaming the volume group!

Answer (score 11):

All answers above took the assumption that the user already knows which partition is the encrypted one. Coming from someone that doesn't like the command line so much, I was expecting some user-friendly answer... So my 2cents here.

1. Open the "disks" application of ubuntu.
2. Locate your mounted hard disk in the left panel.
3. Click on the partition that has "LUKS" in its name: this way you can see its mount point in the "Device" text below (in my case: `/dev/sdb4`).

Then I tried to mount it like adviced above:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb4 someNameForMyVolume
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb4:
```

But got this error:

```
Cannot use device /dev/sdb4 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).
```

Ok, so I guess nautilus has already tried to mount it (because it actually prompted me for the password as I connected the USB, even if it didn't end up showing the decrypted tree). However, the error message is not really helpful because it doesn't tell me where it's already mapped/mounted. But this command helps in this case:

```
$ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb4
Passphrase: 
Error unlocking /dev/sdb4: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Device /dev/sdb4 is already unlocked as /dev/dm-3
```

Aha! So it's `/dev/dm-3`.

However when trying to mount it, it doesn't work:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/dm-3
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d3 is not a mountable filesystem.
```

After much tinkering, I found out that I was running into the `duplicate volume groups` problem (described above by @amenthes) because the commands `sudo vgscan -v` and `sudo vgdisplay` were showing two entries with the same volume group name. However, I found a better way to deal with it than his method (no need to boot into a LiveCD to rename volumegroups!), in this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1wjhzf/recover_luks_encrypted_ubuntu_lv_group_from/), which I'll quote above (just in case that link gets broken...):

If you run `ls -la /dev/mapper/` you should see a `luks-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx` or some such file. That's the mapping that was created when Ubuntu prompted for the encryption password with a dialog but failed to open it (all the dialog did was to call `luksOpen` and map it to that /dev/mapper/luks-xxx file). Now:

1. Make sure your physical volume is available by running the `sudo pvdisplay` command. It should be /dev/mapper/luks-xxx-whatever.
2. Get the uuid of the volume by running `sudo pvs -o +vg_uuid`. The uuid will be the value displayed all the way to the right, containing 7 dash-delimited values. Copy those somewhere as we'll be using them in the next step. DO NOT CONFUSE UUIDS AND COPY DOWN THE WRONG ONE. Only copy the one for your current /dev/mapper/luks-xxx-whatever device.
3. Change the volume group for your old disk by running the following command `sudo vgrename UUIDOFYOURDISKHERE oldhd` You can change the "oldhd" to whatever you want so long as it's differing from the volume group name of your current disk. Performing this step removes the conflict with volume group names which will allow you to now make volumes available.
4. Run the command `vgchange -a y` to make the volumes active.
5. Create a folder for a mountpoint somewhere, e.g.: `sudo mkdir /media/<yourUserName>/someDir`
6. Mount it: `sudo mount /dev/oldhd/root /mnt/oldhd`.
7. After working with your files, you should rename your volumegroup back to `ubuntu-vg` if you want the volume to still be bootable.

Answer (score 9):

*sdb1* here is an example you should input your device name, none of this commands will require root privileges

unlock encrypted disk

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb1
```

after inserting the correct passphrase it will output something like this: *Unlocked /dev/sdb1 as /dev/dm-3*

then mount it to /media/

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/dm-3
```

it should output something like this: *Mounted /dev/dm-3 at /media/yourUserName/sdb*

to unmount it

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/dm-3
```

to lock it again

```
udisksctl lock -b /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: disksctl mount -b /dev/dm-4
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d4 is not a mountable filesystem.

Comment: Sorry did you solve this issue? (with non mountable FS... as I am getting the same)

Comment: Same problem, see this answer for something that worked for me http://askubuntu.com/a/895508/334823

Comment: Like the answer by @David Panella, this mounts the volume on read-only mode. How can it be mount in read-write mode?

Answer (score 3):

I went into several paths from the previous answers and only combination of the previous answers worked for me. He what I did and what went OK, and what went wrong and my workaround.

I have an **LUKS encrypted hard disk** that I need to mount from a live boot USB for **Ubuntu 15.10**. To do so I started with the following command,

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda3
```

where sda3 is the encrypted partition. This command didn't work with me and I am not sure why, so I used the following command:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 my_encrypted_volume
```

it worked with me and I didn't need to install it as it was there in the live boot.

Now, I need to mount the HD, and this was not a straight forward thing: I tried:

```
sudo mkdir /media/my_device
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume /media/my_device
```

But the second command didn't work with me, and hence I have to find a work around which is the following:

```
sudo udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

That was my path .. but you can use the path `dev/mapper/ubuntu` and then double tab to see the rest of options. This mounted the HDD as:

```
Mounted /dev/dm-1 at /media/root/03cf6b80-fa7c-411f-90b9-42a3398529ce
```

Then I used the following command to mount it as `/media/my_device` as following:

```
sudo mount /dev/dm-1 /media/my_device/
```

which worked fine.

**In Summary**

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 my_encrypted_volume
sudo mkdir /media/my_device
sudo udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
sudo mount /dev/dm-1 /media/my_device/
```

Answer (score 3):

For those of us who don't want to use a GUI tool even to determine which partition is encrypted.

- find any encrypted partitions

  ```
  lsblk -lf | grep LUKS
  ```

  `-l` requests the "list" format - we don't need the tree
  `-f` shows us the name of the file system too
  we get something like

  > `sdc2   crypto_LUKS    b09d6209-......`
- unlock the partition that we want (in my case `/dev/sdc2`)

  ```
  udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdc2
  ```

  `-b` means that we are giving the path to a block device
  after entering the passphrase we get an affirmative response with the necessary info for the next step:

  > `Unlocked /dev/sdc2 as /dev/dm-6`
- mount the newly created device (`dm` stand for *device manager*)

  ```
  udisksctl mount -b /dev/dm-6
  ```

  Again we get an affirmative response with useful info:

  > `Mounted /dev/dm-6 at /media/g/Data.`

  (`g` being my username on this system, `Data` is the label I used for that partition)

  It may be the case that your desktop system/file manager has already automatically mounted the device, or you did it yourself before. Then you get something like

  > `Error mounting /dev/dm-6: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.AlreadyMounted: Device /dev/dm-6 is already mounted at '/media/g/Data'.`

  This is no problem, you can access the data from the encrypted partition anyway.
- access the data: `ls /media/g/Data`
- unmount the device again (use the same name you used for mounting, the command is `unmount`, **not** `umount` :-) )

  ```
  udisksctl unmount -b /dev/dm-6
  ```

  If the device is not busy you will get

  > `Unmounted /dev/dm-6.`
- Now lock the partition again (you have to remember the name of the partition)

  ```
  udisksctl lock -b /dev/sdc2
  ```

  You will get

  > `Locked /dev/sdc2.`
- optionally power down the complete external disk

  ```
  udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdc
  ```

  With a graphical desktop you may get an error here:

  > `Error powering off drive: The drive in use: Device /dev/sdc3 is mounted (udisks-error-quark, 14)`

  In that case you can use `udisksctl` to unmount the partitions one by one until you succeed. The `udisksctl power-off` does not return any messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount it in two steps, and I have a script example.

Note: the service udiskctl will mount things under /media, it's more designed for desktop users mounting usb sticks. 
If you want to mount the device somewhere else, it's not the solution you are looking for.

Here is what I worked out. 
In this example, my encrypted device is a partition made with lvm, but this doesn't really matter. It is an ext4-formatted partition. In its encrypted form, it lives at

```
/dev/myvg/opt1
```

an encrypted partion is "opened" (decrypted) like this

```
  STEP 1:  sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/myvg/opt1 opt1_opened
```

(this is where you enter the passphrase)

the last argument is a temporary reference to the decrypted block device.
The 'mapping' disappears when you reboot so you can choose a different name each time, if you want.

it is now visible as a device:

```
ls /dev/mapper
control  myvg-opt1  myvg-root  opt1_opened
```

You can mount this device: we now have an ext4 device.
To make it convenient, add a line in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/opt1_opened /opt1   ext4    noauto,users    0       0
```

and make the mount point (in my case: `sudo mkdir /opt1`, and then setup permissions as you wish)
If you used the name opt1_opened in Step 1, then this is the second step to mount it:

```
STEP 2: mount /opt1   #the fstab line lets users mount, so no need for sudo
```

and it's mounted.

Hence, a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#needs to be run sudo
read -s -p "Enter LUKS password: " luks_password
printf $luks_password | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/myvg/opt1 opt1_opened --key-file -
sudo -u tim mount /opt1
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is `gio mount -d /dev/dm-x` (no sudo).

Previous answers show a disconnect with the Nautilus or Nemo way of mounting, since you need to enter the LUKS passphrase even though it is previously cached in the user keyring from the GUI. Using `gio` automatically uses the passphrase previously stored by Nautilus or Nemo.

For a more detailed answer, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394320/what-command-does-nemo-use-to-mount-drives/536842#536842

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the same...

The `mkdir` steps were my reason to look further, also I've modified `policykit` to allow my user to mount without asking first for the root passwd and then for the encrypted volume password, so the `sudo` was also over kill.

My solution I found was the use of `gvfs-mount` from the `gvfs-bin` package. Now with a `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sda7` I'm asked for the encrypted password only and it's mounted under `/media/VOLUME_LABEL`.

Comment: Not getting luck with this.  Steps I took: first, `cat /proc/partitions` to identify the /dev label for the drive.  Second, `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdf1`.  This gives the error "No volume for device file /dev/sdf1".  This looks close, though!

Comment: It works for me. Strangely not through `/dev/disks/by-label` or `/by-uuid`, but only by `/dev/sdxx`

Comment: The message "No volume for device file /dev/sdf1" will be present until you delete according device from /etc/fstab. After that gvfs-mount works as designed

Comment: FYI: `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdaX` worked perfectly for me in Linux Mint 17.3 -- No password required as with the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i have a working solution guys, as discussed previously the reason you're getting `mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'` error is because by default your linux machine assigns the same VG name to external hard drive, hence all the partition on external HDD are inactive.

This is what you need to do:

1. unplug your external hard-drive and take note of your internal VG UUID using (`sudo vgdisplay command`),
2. now plug in your external hard drive and rename the VG group of your
   EXTERNAL HDD (not internal, this will break your box) (`vgrename UUID_Number [new-group]`).
3. Check that new name is updated in VGdiplay, now activate new VGroup (`vgchange [new_group] -a y`), check all partitions are activated (`lvscan`).
4. Now you should see all your
   partitions under `ls /dev/mapper/[new_group]`, all you need to do is
   mount the partition (`mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/[new_group]-data
   /zez`)

Answer (score 0):

On my chromebook with (crouton) Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 I find that when I issue:

sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda1 my_encrypted_volume

per the above posting and enter my passphrase, I get "No key available with this passphrase."  However, by accident I've found (and very strange it is!) the whole thing works when I add "--debug" to the cryptsetup command!  I am then able to mount the volume and access the files.

Asking the file manager Thunar to do the mounting results "Not authorized to perform operation." error.  I am unable to figure a way around that, but since I can do the mount at the command line, that's somewhat acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

#### It's an LVM issue, which (mentioned above/below) needs to be installed.

[From Unix/Linux community:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339011/how-do-i-mount-an-lvm-partition/339621#339621)

```
$ sudo apt-get install lvm2        #This step may or may not be required.
$ sudo pvscan                      #Use this to verify your LVM partition(s) is/are detected.
$ sudo vgscan                      #Scans for LVM Volume Group(s)
$ sudo vgchange -ay                #Activates LVM Volume Group(s)
$ sudo lvscan                      #Scans for available Logical Volumes
$ sudo mount /dev/YourVolGroup00/YourLogVol00 /YourMountPoint
```

---

Referenced these on route to the above answer:

- [How to mount a device in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux)
- [Mount encrypted volumes from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line)
- [Cannot mount LUKS encrypted partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003967/cannot-mount-luks-encrypted-partition-from-live-usb)
- [mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'](https://superuser.com/questions/1134255/luks-on-ubuntu-16-04-unknown-filesystem-type-crypto-luks)
- [External hard disk detected but not mounting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696043/external-harddisk-detected-but-not-mounting)
- [Mounting a drive and accessing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78114/mounting-a-drive-and-accessing-it)
- [External Hard Drive not recognized on Debian](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/external-hard-drive-not-recognized-on-debian-sid-4175483581/)

*Clarify*: `/YourMountPoint` can be anything, e.g. `/media/user/external`