# How to access hard drive files from liveCD?

Tags: mount, live-cd, live-environment

I don't know what files or file types are there on the hard drive nor do I know the file system in which the hard disk is written on. I am not able to view it in the **home** folder after booting from the liveCD.

Comment: Does Gparted not tell you what filesystems you have on your disk? (As I remember it should do)

Comment: You should nt look in Home Folder, but on the left pane of **Nautilus**, identify the correct partition and mount it. With that said, this question lacks detail, and it would help to add some.

Answer (score 10):

When running a **live session**, you *cannot* access a computer's hard drive via `/home` directory or **Home** folder.

You do need to identify and click on the *partition's label or name* in the *side pane* of **Nautilus** to *mount* it, that is if you are running Ubuntu with GNOME desktop.

[image]

For KDE's **Dolphin**:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer!!!!

Comment: @Peachy I changed something in my /etc/network/interfaces file which completely blocks Ubuntu from booting.
I'm using Kubuntu LiveCD and tried to access the disk but while I can mount it, all I can view are the home folders.
I tried sudo su - but it didn't give better results>

Any idea how I could read this file and correct the wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: I just brazenly stole your images for an [answer](http://superuser.com/a/681118/151431) I posted over on [su]. With proper attribution of course, but I'd be happy to remove them if you mind.

Comment: The unmounted device might not show up in Nautilus...

Comment: None of these work for my Xfce (I don't see any device besides filesystem). Could you give a path or usual paths?
Thanks :)

Comment: @Ignorante Look what devices are listed under /dev and guess at which one you need. If all else fails, use the terminal and perform a `mount` command.

Comment: It will show *Unauthorized access* when opening or mounting the other volumes. And if you open home by as *Nautilus*  you can not see the unmounted volumes. So I don't think that answer will work. = -1

Comment: (-1) Nautilus does not show "Devices" for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open GUI application Disks, and find the drive you want to mount from the pane on the left. Within that drive, find the partition you want to mount using the drive's partition diagram.

When you click on the partition, the information beneath the partition diagram will show the drive's device identifier, in a line like:

```
Device: /dev/sd??
```

Replacing the question marks above with your device identifier, use command line 'mount' to mount the partition:

```
TODO
```

For an encrypted partition, see [this answer to "Mount encrypted volumes from command line?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/279218/11307)