# data loss on crash during ubuntu upgrading 12.04 to 14.04 on dual boot pc

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, data-loss

While Upgrading ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 I had a crash. When I try to boot from ubuntu (I have dual boot -ubuntu vista 7- Sony Vaio laptop) I get the following messages:

target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init/
No init found. try passing init=bootarg
BusyBox v.1.21.1 built in shell (ash)
initramfs _

I can still boot from Windows 7 but I seem not able to recover the data on ubuntu partition from there.

Ubuntu partition is 15 Giga.
Is it there a way to recover the data on ubuntu partition?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Because it sounds like u will be able to backup your data when accessing it:

Boot from LiveDVD, then you can access the Data in the Linux partition.

If necessary: [Further explanation here for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190239/how-to-access-hard-drive-files-from-livecd) and in lot of other questions here and forums all over the web ;)

Comment: I have done that but I could not find any Linux partition, all I found was the filesystem and under device the pc HD. I neither I was able to find the ubuntu data

Comment: have you tried 'sudo fdisk -l'? What is the output?