# I need to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 after erasing a lot of files and ubuntu won't start anymore

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I played around without looking in terminal and I somehow started to erase all the ubuntu system files. Now all I want to do is access my photos and transfer them over to my portable hard drive but I can't do that using a LiveUSB with ubuntu or with the Boot-repair liveUSB.

My only option I understand is to reinstall ubuntu but I'm afraid that doing that it will erase both the system files and the other partitions files where my photos are.

Comment: Get 2 USB devices - put the Ubuntu installation files onto 1 devices, and format the other device to use as a storage space for your photos.  Boot from the Ubuntu device, choosing 'Try Ubuntu', and copy your photos and files to the second USB device.  Ensure that they have been copied!  Remove the second device, and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: It is not possible to copy them intact. If I copy them then I can't open them. I can't even open them in 'Try Ubuntu'.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean when you say "It is not possible to copy them intact"

Comment: If I copy them then I can't open them or view them. Just get an error saying I have no 'rights' to view them.

Comment: Your username on the 'Try Ubuntu' USB is different than the username on the disk - you will need to change the permissions on the copied files to be able to open them.  Please review [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190239/how-to-access-hard-drive-files-from-livecd) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/78699/283721)

Comment: I can view the files with Nautilus but I still can't copy them to a usb.

Comment: Make sure that the 2nd USB is writable:  You may want to reformat that USB using your liveCD

Comment: Yes this doesn't work. It is only possible to view the pictures on the computer but it is not possible to upload or transfer them to a usb or a portable hard drive. Thank you for showing me nautilus but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If your photos are in Another partition it is easy to recover via Live USB :) in case of reinstalling Ubuntu. Make sure that you're formatting a correct partition.

Comment: I need a real answer with steps on how to do this you claim is easy.

Comment: Burn ISO in USB drive, boot it, take in to external hard disk

Comment: As I've said. Done this and I can't copy them or view them as I have no rights to view them.