# How Do I Access HDD OS When Booting from Live-USB?

Tags: dell, live-usb, directory, inspiron

I've been advised to check some log files in the flaky 14.04 pre-installed by Dell on my Inspiron 15-3552 laptop. I've booted from a 14.04 live-USB but I reckon the folders shown under Files/Computer are the ones in the temporary Ram-held OS as the edit to /etc/rc.local to disable Bluetooth on startup, which I made before the OS went flaky, is absent. I guess it's necessary to use Terminal, but how do I get to the correct /var/log/apt folder which holds the log files relating to the OS on the HDD?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/190239/how-to-access-hard-drive-files-from-livecd

Answer (score 0):

Mount the root partition of the internal drive at /mnt,

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt
```

where x is the drive letter (x = a for the first drive), and n is the partition number (often n = 1 or n = 5), so for example

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

The following command line

```
sudo ls -l /mnt/var/log/apt
```

will list the files in the folder you want to examine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a command-line solution, try this -

You must first identify the partition you need to mount.  You can do that using the program `gparted` or the command `lsblk`. It will be of the format sdXY where X is a letter and Y is a number.

Once you have identified the partition, you can mount it as follows.

Create a mount point `sudo mkdir /media/mount`

Mount the partition `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /media/mount`

Now you can use `nano` to look at the logfiles `nano /media/mount/var/log/[directory of interest]/[logfile of interest]`