# Moving Ubuntu from old HDD to SDD revisited

Tags: mount, ssd

I am trying to do what was asked - and apparently solved - in a question from about 10 years ago:

[How to move ubuntu to an ssd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40372/how-to-move-ubuntu-to-an-ssd)

I want to move an existing, working Ubuntu 20.04 install across to a new SSD and not use the old HDD following the move.

I created a partition on the new SSD using gparted, and booted from a Live DVD as suggested in the top answer in the thread above.

However, when I attempt to mount the new drives (which show up as sda and sdb when I type lsblk at the terminal prompt), the following occurs:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda

mount: /dev/sda: can't find in /etc/fstab
```

The same result occurred with

```
sudo mount /media/sda
mount: /media/sda: can't find in /etc/fstab
```

and if I try to mount a partition rather than the whole drive:

```
sudo mount /media/sda1
mount: /dev/sda1: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

So, I know it's a numpty question, but what am I doing wrong?  In a way I'm not surprised by these error messages, because the Live DVD Ubuntu presumably doesn't know anything about the drives on the machine or their partitions in /etc/fstab, since I haven't told it.  But where do I go from here?

I also tried the Nautilus based method described here [how to access hard drive files from live cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190239/how-to-access-hard-drive-files-from-livecd) but Nautilus does not show devices (as reported in one of the comments on that page).

Do I need to edit fstab?  Strange that none of the 10-years-ago guys mentioned that, if it is the case.

Many thanks,

Eric
Ubuntu 20.04
Dell Precision T1650

Comment: Reinstalling is BY FAR the best option. Do NOT follow that old answer, it isn't applicable to new UEFI based machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating Linux can be done with [clonezilla.](https://clonezilla.org/) Works like a charm.

Now mount require at least two params to achieve what your are trying to do:

> mount what where

if you do not tell mount "where", it goes to look at /etc/fstab to find where. So your line could be:

> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

That will mount the partition at /mnt. One important thing. /dev/sda is the disk. /dev/sda(n) is the partition.

Comment: Thank you - it was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part about how to supply arguments to mount.