# Mounting encrypted LUKS partition from Live CD

Tags: boot, filesystem, lvm, initramfs, luks

### Error to begin with, can't boot

I had to do a hard reboot of my computer, and when booting up it (initramfs I think) gave an error:

```
mount: mounting /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory 

Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

### Trying to mount from Live-CD

I have very, very important data on it, so instead of trying to fix the boot system (or whatever I should call it), I would just like to mount it and copy the important files to a USB stick.

I have tried several guides without luck. The most straight forward seems to be [Mount encrypted volumes from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line). Here is what I've done:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 myvolume
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mkdir mountpoint
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/myvolume m
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/myvolume mountpoint
mount: /dev/mapper/myvolume already mounted or mountpoint busy
```

The mountpoint folder is not busy, it's an empty folder that I can delete if I want. I believe `/dev/mapper/myvolume` is not mounted, well since I have not done it, and since the following returns nothing `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mount -l | grep myvolume`.

I don't know what information is relevant for the question. In my struggle I have learned the names of dozens of new commands, and it would be too much text to post the information from all of them. So please tell me what additional information is relevant.

### Output of blkid

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="04BD-5CB0" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="4b4af9b9-1290-431a-bfcb-3b8e24d52c54" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="09e172eb-1080-4f68-80fb-1386ac0491b6" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="369D-508C" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/mapper/myvolume: UUID="0DkUPe-3S13-zNOA-5wi0-uzPb-CCB8-9m14C1" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="44b26e6d-cb85-4949-b0e8-9421ab515d03" TYPE="swap"
```

### Complete summary from Ubuntu Boot-Repair

I did not try to restore anything, I only used the tool to print a summary of relevant information. Tool used: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Result: https://www.jottit.com/gvwbu/ (many pages)

Comment: Have you managed to get kyodake's commands to work?

Comment: No I did not, but I dont remember why. I ended up paying a company to first make an image and then fix the boot issue, because I was under a lot of pressure.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

You need to Boot into a Live DVD/USB environment and open up a terminal window:

Press `Applications` --- `Accessories`--- `Terminal`

Install required packages using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup
```

Probe required module using the following command:

```
sudo modprobe dm-crypt
```

You find out which drive it was with the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You must mount /dev/sda3 myvolume , You need to use cryptsetup:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sde3 myvolume
```

Now the device is accessible under /dev/mapper/myvolume

Scan for LVM volumes and choose the right volume group name that you are looking for:

```
sudo vgscan
```

Suppose it is `system`, activate that volume:

```
sudo vgchange -ay system
```

To find out your root volume, use the following command:

```
sudo lvs
```

Suppose it is `root system` you can mount it with the following command:

```
sudo mount /dev/system/root /mnt/
```

To work in volume use the following commands

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Answer (score 3):

You have LVM volumes inside the LUKS container. You should let the sytem know about them.

Run

```
sudo vgscan
sudo vgchange -a y
```

and then

```
mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt/whateveryoulike
```

Comment: Tried that. Then I get `sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root mountpoint`. Is it supposed to recognize the filesystem itself, because apparently it doesn't. I'm not sure what FS it is, it's the standard Ubuntu setup, if choosing encrypted disk. If I add `-t ext4` (or ext2, ext3), I get a rather long error `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Comment: post output of `sudo blkid`

Comment: @solsTiCe How to evaluate output of `sudo vgscan`? I get `failed connection` in the thread here http://askubuntu.com/q/768916/25388