# Restore Ubuntu after cancelled upgrade to 16 - contents of usr/lib64 now missing

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, restore

I let someone use my laptop and they cancelled the upgrade from 14 to 16 after accidently starting it.  We believe this resulted in the contents of usr/lib64 being deleted.  So far, the only victim has been my ability to use my CAC reader because the file libcackey.so is missing.  When I try to reinstall CACKEY, I get errors related to other missing .so files.  I'm assuming that as I use my laptop more, I'm going to notice other issues because this folder is now empty.

Is there an easy way to restore the contents of the usr/lib64 folder or reinstall everything that was installed there?  What will happen if I either reinstall 14 or upgrade to 16?  Do I need to start from scratch again?

Comment: You could try from a LiveCD mounting the drive like in this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/28100/231142  Then try installing.  If it is missing too much, you probably are looking at a reinstallation of the OS.

Comment: Thanks Terrance.  I'm somewhat of a Linux noob.  I'm using LVMs and LUKS FDE.  Will any of that matter when I try to use the solution in the link you provided?

Comment: Actually, yes, you will have to setup the LVM support for the live session to work.  Take a look at this one:  https://askubuntu.com/a/653460/231142

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to leave work for the day and will try this tomorrow.  One last question, would it be easier if I just restarted the upgrade to 16?

Comment: You can try it.  With the loss of that folder though it is hard to say.  You might be looking at a reinstallation of the OS itself.  It won't hurt to try first before reinstalling the whole OS.