# Ubuntu is stuck after I enter the sda_3 crypt while booting up

Tags: xubuntu, 19.04

Earlier today I tried to do something with the settings so as to play games at higher refresh rate 
Here is the command I entered the command prompt

xfconf-query --channel=xfwm4 --property=/general/use_compositing --type=bool --toggle

I am a Linux noob, I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.
Please help me so as to restore my system to the previous working state or at least make it work without loosing my data
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First things first: get the data copied to another drive. You'll want to boot into a live USB and mount your partition, then copy that data off. Here's a thread to start: [Mounting encrypted LUKS partition from Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653408/mounting-encrypted-luks-partition-from-live-cd)

I don't know anything about the command you ran and how to recover from it, but after messing up multiple encrypted installations with modifications, I've learned it's often faster just to reinstall than fall down the rabbit hole. I run a very slim set of programs, with most of my important stuff in the cloud or home server, so that may just be my personal preference.