# System won't boot. Kernel panic. Unable to mount root fs

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I am in desperate need of accessing something on my encrypted Ubuntu laptop which stopped booting randomly today. I tried loading in recovery mode, but
I just keep getting the following kernel panic:

Is there any way to fix this?

[image: kernel]

Comment: Looks like the hard drive has failed or there is corruption in the file system. It's likely that you will need to restore from backups and reinstall the system. You may been to replace the hard drive depending on the reason for the file system being corrupted

Comment: @Nmath: Thank you for the quick reply! Do you think there is a realistic way to retrieve a picture from this hard drive? The HD is encrypted, i have the key, and the picture is encrypted via pgp for which i know the passphrase as well?

Comment: If the file system is damaged and encrypted, then no, you probably won't be able to retrieve anything off it. You'll need to get it from your backups.

Comment: I think it’s worth trying from a live usb session. I’ve never tried accessing an encrypted partition from a live session, but you’ve not got much to lose. I take it from your other comments that you don’t have a backup.  Have a look at this post which might get you there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/653408/mounting-encrypted-luks-partition-from-live-cd

Comment: Thank you Will! Yea no backup. Ill give it a go with usb again, i think i may be boned regardless because the file im after is encrypted with pgp for which i have the passphrase but not the key files anymore. I think the file was encrypted passphrase only tho.