# External harddisk detected but not mounting

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, disk

I have a WD MyPassport that is NTFS formatted with only 1 partition, and **works perfectly fine on Windows**. It was working well with Ubuntu until a few days ago (points 3 and 4 explains what changes I might have made).

I'm using an Ubuntu 15.04 64bit with 3.19.0-32-generic.

The HDD is getting detected, but I am unable to mount it.

1. Here is how it shows up on the Disks application

   [image: screenshot of Disks]
2. `lsusb` shows the hard disk info. Connecting to a different USB port does not help

   ```
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1058:0741 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
   ```
3. My internal HDD has one ext4 and two NTFS partitions, and they show up fine on `fstab`, **but my external HDD does not**

   ```
   # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
   #
   # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
   # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
   # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
   #
   # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
   # / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
   UUID=964a0a16-e279-4551-a71f-0b8594a42170 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   /dev/disk/by-uuid/280E83930E835928 /mnt/280E83930E835928 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,noauto 0 0
   /dev/disk/by-uuid/8A9CAF0D9CAEF33D /media/usr/part1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
   /swap   swap    swap    defaults        0       0
   ```
4. The `/swap` partition is actually created by me using `fallocate` and `mkswap` for hibernation using swap file as described in the [Debian Wiki Hibernation Manual](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition). Perhaps my HDD issues have something to do with this - I am not able to figure that out
5. Output of some commands upon request

   - `$sudo fdisk -l`

     ```
     Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
     Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
     Disklabel type: dos
     Disk identifier: 0x397a8933

     Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
     /dev/sda1  *         2048     718847     716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
     /dev/sda2          718848  471861247  471142400 224.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
     /dev/sda3       471861248  786434047  314572800   150G  6 FAT16
     /dev/sda4       786434048 1953521663 1167087616 556.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

     Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
     Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
     Disklabel type: dos
     Disk identifier: 0x0005f107

     Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
     /dev/sdb1        2048 3906963455 3906961408  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
     ```
   - `blkid` gave no output for the external disk `/dev/sdb1`

     ```
     $ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
     $
     ```
6. **BIG EDIT - ABLE TO MOUNT HDD VIA COMMAND LINE.** How to automount?

   - Created a directory `/media/usr/external/` and ran `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usr/external`. HDD mounted perfectly.
   - Disks application now recognizes the mounted HDD
     [image: Disks application now recognizes the mounted HDD]
   - I tried to change the Mount options to make it similar to my internal HDD (turning `Automatic Mount Options` ON did not help). The `Mount at Startup` option made no difference when checked.
     [image: mount options]
     This is what my `fstab` looks like now (removed `swap` entry)

     ```
     # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
     #
     # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
     # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
     # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
     #
     # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
     # / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
     UUID=964a0a16-e279-4551-a71f-0b8594a42170 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
     /dev/disk/by-uuid/280E83930E835928 /mnt/280E83930E835928 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,noauto 0 0
     /dev/disk/by-uuid/8A9CAF0D9CAEF33D /media/usr/part1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
     ```
   - After disconnecting and reconnecting the HDD - it does not automount. Trying to mount from Nautilus gives me the following error. 
     [image: Only root can mount]

How do I go about automounting my HDD, now that the mounting problems have been solved? Earlier I never had to `sudo` for mounting - it just connected.

Comment: can you [edit] your post and post the output of this command`sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Your unknown Partitioning must be something Windows specific, maybe something like "dynamic partitions".  What does Windows say about it?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sd1`?

Comment: @Neil - posted the output of  `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I assumed you meant `/dev/sdb1` which is the external HDD, However, neither `sudo blkid /dev/sd1` nor `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1` gave any output.


I did get `UUIDs` and `PARTUUIDs` for my internal HDD `/dev/sda`. Do you want me to post them?

Comment: @ubfan1 - the HDD was working fine with Ubuntu up until a few days ago.

Comment: @3l4ng: I meant the first partition of your internal drive. It just turned out to appear at path `/dev/sdb1` in the Gnome Disks screenshot at the top of your question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - thank you for the clarification, but there was no output either way. What does this indicate?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't have a plausible explanation, that covers 1) Windows being able to read the file system, 2) `fdisk` reading the partition table without complaint, and 3) none of Gnome Disks, `blkid` and the NTFS driver recognizing the file system header. My best explanation is an issue with the USB stack between the external drive case and your Linux system.

Comment: I recommend to look for issue reports about drive cases with the sam USB ID (which you can find out with `lsusb`).

Comment: @DavidFoerster - was able to mount manually. However, cannot get automount working. Please see point #6

Answer (score 22):

This will solve the problem:

- Install ntfs-3g using: `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`
- Run `sudo fdisk -l` to figure out where the mount point is
- Run `sudo ntfsfix -b /dev/{mount_point}`

Comment: I had a similar problem after power outage. USB hard-drive was detected but not mounted. Your answer has solved my problem.

Comment: Worked like a breeze for me, thanks @SKullZzZz! The last command for me was `sudo ntfsfix -b /dev/sdb1`

Answer (score 3):

I tried ntfs-3g but had no luck. In the end, I plugged the drive into a Windows 10 PC and ran chkdsk. It fixed the problem and the drive works in Ubuntu machines now.

In windows, click the start button and type cmd
Open the cmd app (like a terminal in Linux)

```
chkdsk E: /f
```

Remember to replace the E with the letter that your drive mapped to when you plugged it in.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mkdir /media/External-HDD
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g -y
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/External-HDD
```

Comment: I have not yet tried the `ntfs-3g` drivers. I will look to these if no other Ubuntu solutions work

Comment: @3l4ng Ok I hope it works.

Comment: turns out `ntfs-3g` was already installed. I can mount the HDD manually via command line, but automounting does not seem to work now

Comment: @3l4ng Try [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) tutorial to automount HDD