# What does the -b switch for udisksctl do?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I had to mount an encrypted external hdd using the command-line earlier this evening. Thanks to these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/750934/381089) I was successful, but I'm left wondering what the`-b` switch for the `udisksctl` command does. I looked through the man page and there's no mention of it. Is it to signal that what's being decrypted is a block device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `-b` (`--block-device`) option is for choosing a block device](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/udisksctl.1.html) like `/dev/sdb1`. You can find this out by typing `udisksctl unlock --help` for instance; replace `unlock` with `mount`, `unmount` and `lock` and you will see the `-b` option is used in the same way for all 4 cases.

Answer (score 3):

The udisks command line tool `udisksctl`  is a command-line program used to interact with the [udisksd(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/udisksd.8.html) daemon process.The `-b` option denotes a block-device like `/dev/sdb1`