# ubuntu--vg-root does not exist after formatting boot partition

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, ssd, initramfs

I was recently trying to format a disk on my ubuntu 16.04 desktop with gparted and I accidentally formatted my boot partition which deleted GRUB and everything else on the partition. I managed to reinstall GRUB with boot repair. However, when I attempted a reboot, I was greeted with an initramfs console. Upon typing "exit" the console said that ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. When I actually change to the directory where it is supposed to be, it is not there. I am using a fully encrypted ssd (operating system), and another 2 tb hard drive (all the other stuff). I have really important data on the ssd and I really need to get it back. Any and all help is highly appreciated!!
Thanks you in advance!!

-Kolkoz P.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-) With great security comes great responsibility...**  Do you have any kind of system backup of your SSD?  That would be the easiest...  in any case: immediately do a `dd` of your drive to something else so you can try multiple times on the same image...

Comment: Hey! I'm love the friendly community here and I want to get more involved with it. Thank you so much for responding to mys questions! I never got th chance to make a backup of it, but I will do a dd of it as soon to possible.

Comment: Okok, I makes dd of drive and im ready to try stuff on it.

Comment: OK, start by booting from DVD and using [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/63598/344926) to mount the drive.