# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot after trying to free disk space on /boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, encryption

A while ago I started getting messages on my laptop saying that my /boot partition on Ubuntu was running low on disk space, so I followed a tutorial online to remove old packages. It was a while ago and I can't remember what I typed in, but it seemed to work. The next time I booted my computer up though it showed this error

"Kernal panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)"

It comes up with this error regardless of what boot option I choose. Ubuntu is the only OS on the computer and takes up the whole drive. Both the full disk and home folder were encrypted with separate passcodes on installation though.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  I would start by looking into what you did.  If you used term/bash look at `~/.bash_history`  (the file .bash_history in default user directory) which has a list of my commands (mine include dates & time but default is without) .. thus avoiding any guess.   As you can't boot; I'd boot a 'live' media (such as Ubuntu install media) then `mount` your drive and then explore your fs (filesystem) & scan your command history.  (here's a link on mounting an encrypted partition https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line)

Comment: A link to the instructions you followed would be helpful. Some out there are quite dangerous.