# Unable to mount unencrypted drive from live USB

Tags: mount, cryptsetup, unlock

My son kindly crashed my laptop and when I restarted it, [cryptsetup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cryptsetup.8.html) did not accept my password (going into 60 minute delay).  I cannot launch Ubuntu 18.04 that I have installed on my laptop SSD, but I can launch with a Live USB and unlock the laptop SSD using the Disks utility.

I see no way to mount the drive. I also tried to access the drive through command prompt and I get an error message, as shown below.

```
$ fdisk -l
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/nvme0n1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
```

Then try to unlock it:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 my_enc_hard
```

And get this message

```
Device /dev/nvme0n1 doesn't exist or access denied.
```

Comment: Please add your error message to the question with [edit]. Take a look at https://milosophical.me/blog/2014/mounting-lukslvm-from-a-liveusb.html and https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line

Comment: I use this to see what drives I see:

# fdisk -l
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop6: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/nvme0n1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied

Comment: Then try to unlcok it:

cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 my_enc_hard

Device /dev/nvme0n1 doesn't exist or access denied.

I don't understand what is the issue;

When I use 

sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 my_enc_hard

I am not prompted to enter my password.

Comment: I also don't understand why I can open the drive with Disks utility from USB, but I am not prompted to enter the password when I try cryptsetup luksOpen ...