# ubuntu boot issues

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning

I recently made a live USB stick of Lubuntu and ran boot repair on my system. I was given this URL. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G9Zpd7CJTx/. Please help as I already have a partition set up and an extended partition for linux ubuntu but my system wont boot up anymore. I removed nautilus to free up some space but that didn't work. It is usually stuck on the part of the boot where it checks for daily apt upgrades and clean.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I don’t think I can help you with this technically but I do suggest you clarify your question. I’m guessing you have an install of Ubuntu or Lubuntu that was working. Then you got the problem with boot hanging at daily updates. How and why did you remove nautilus when the system won’t boot and you seem to have plenty of space? Can you get to a tty prompt? Is it your understanding that sda5 is encrypted? I’ve no experience of working with encrypted disks so you may not be able to follow this suggestion but on an “normal”system I would try to disable the services that are failing

Comment: Correct, I had installed ubuntu on my hard drive and it was working up until I had updated it to 18.04. My encrypted partition is sdb5. I have a live USD of Lubuntu which I am using currently to connect to the internet and attempt to mount the partition that is encrypted. sometimes it says it cant find the partition in /etc/fsab, i think that is what it says.

Comment: I think you will need a key or password to unlock the disk. Do you have one? Suggest you research troubleshooting crypto_LUKS disks.

Comment: yeah I have the password to unlock the disk, what im not sure is how to secure a mount point for the partition. i think that might solve the problem can you help with that?

Comment: Like I said above I am not familiar with working with encrypted volumes. Use Google or the search facility on here. “Mount encrypted volume” found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line. There are many others

Comment: I just reinstalled ubuntu there was nothing really on that old hard drive that I needed and it had been encrypted for extra security reasons