# Getting files from an internal harddrive that ran ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, encryption, restore

So my last laptop broke and I tried to restore the files from my internal ssd harddrive. I bought an adapter from the harddrive and plugged it into another computer running ubuntu. It asked me for a passphrase, i entered it but it only mounted a small folder containing things I don't care about.

[image]

[image]

Update:
Screenshot with Parittion 3 LUKS selected

[image]

Screenshot with Paritition LVM2 PV
[image]

Comment: I unlocked it with the passphrase and it shows me the small folder in the above picture. It's not the files in the desktop i wanted

Comment: Try manually mounting it on the command line.... if you need to unlock it on the command line use the udisksctl command `udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda#`... `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda#`... I believe this mounts in /media... other options to investigate with on the manpage...

Comment: When I try to mount it manually it says >Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda3 is not a mountable filesystem.

Comment: @user68186 I did just that thank you

Comment: @user68186 I just did thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I see the LVM2 PV is not mounted. for putting up with me. Unfortunately I don't know much about LVMs. I hope someone else will see these screenshots and will be able to help you with the next step. In the mean while, following the steps in the **section** [How to mount LVM volume](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-an-lvm-volume-partition-command/) may be helpful. Start from the command `sudo vgscan` down the list. You may want to copy and paste the commands and their outputs from terminal to your question. Best of luck!

Comment: Here is some mention of how to mount encrypted LVMs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line