# Deleted EFI Partition, see my old encrypted Partition, WANT MY FILES BACK. How?

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I need a step-by-step guide made for a toddler to help me get this computer recognizing what I assume is the still-present/available partition that contains all of my files & settings.

I deleted the EFI partition, used a Live CD/Boot to get Ubuntu 20.04 back, but am stuck wondering how I tell the computer to once again use my encrypted partition (the one I believe has all my files).

Using GParted shows that I have just two partitions:
(partition) unallocated, (File system) unallocated, size: 1.22 GiB, and
(partition) /dev/nvme0n1p3, (File system) Encrypted, size: 237.26 GiB. Although GParted is telling me that my 237 GiB partition is not mounted and has unknown file system.

However, when I use Terminal & do `sudo fdisk -l`, it shows 11 partitions, which includes the ScanDisk memory stick I used for the Live Boot.

Basically, HOW (and I do mean every minute detail) do I make an EFI partition so that I can boot without the memory stick, & get the computer to read the partition with my data???

Also, I never "installed" Ubuntu when I was given the option. I "tried it out" or whatever. I've already spent literally hours trying to find solutions to this, but NO ONE apparently has the problem of recovering old partitions; it all seems that they're either doing clean boots, or just starting over. I see that the partition's there, and the amount of GiB seems right, so I know there must be a way! Help me Internet!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can mount your encrypted partition and copy you files to a backup. EFI is not needed for that.

Comment: Some details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption/Troubleshooting  You have to have recreated the ESP - efi system partition to reinstall grub.