# Mount encrypted volume in read/write mode

Tags: command-line, mount, encryption, luks

The canonical method to mount encrypted volumes from the command line on later Ubuntu editions [involves `udisksctl`](https://askubuntu.com/a/279218/177437). However, that recipe mounts the volume in read-only mode.

```
$ udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdd1
Passphrase:
Unlocked /dev/sdd1 as /dev/dm-1.

$ ls -la /dev/mapper
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     100 apr  2 12:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    4860 apr  2 12:58 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 mrt 28 19:27 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 apr  2 12:58 luks-1841d2d1-4ce7-46e4-805e-0be262199e7d -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 apr  2 12:53 NOAB -> ../dm-0

$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/luks-1841d2d1-4ce7-46e4-805e-0be262199e7d
Mounted /dev/dm-1 at /media/user/NOAB

$ cd /media/user/NOAB

$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Read-only file system
```

Going through the `udisksctl` manual I understand it takes the same arguments as good old `mount`. So I gave it a try:

```
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/mapper/luks-1841d2d1-4ce7-46e4-805e-0be262199e7d
Unmounted /dev/dm-1.

$ udisksctl mount -o umask=0 -b /dev/mapper/luks-1841d2d1-4ce7-46e4-805e-0be262199e7d
Error mounting /dev/dm-1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.OptionNotPermitted: Mount option `umask=0' is not allowed
```

Is there some other way of passing the `umask` argument to `udisksctl`? Or any other method to mount the volume in read and write mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be rooted with `udisksctl`, perhaps a limitation with this tool. The solution is to decrypt the volume with [`cryptsetup`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup) and mount directly with `mount` (log below). It also functions correctly mounting to the `/media/user` folder.

```
$ sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdd1 NOABdev
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdd1:

$ mkdir -p ~/mount/test

$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/NOABdev ~/mount/test

$ touch ~/mount/test/test.txt
```