# How to reinstall Ubuntu on encrypted SSD?

Tags: system-installation, encryption

Ubuntu crashed and I am no longer able to boot. I'd like to keep or recover files on the encrypted SSD.

[image]

Comment: With encryption the most common and quickest solution is total reinstall & restore your data from your backups. With encryption you have to have good backups. Recover files on encrypted drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382995 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line